# Qual é a utilidade dos arrays em r?

Tags: array, r

`vector`, `matrix`, `data.frame` e `list` são amplamente utilizados em análise de dados e em peguntas da tag `r` aqui no *site*. Particularmente, não vejo aplicabilidade do `array` em `r`. Por exemplo:

```
vec_1 <- c(2:4)
vec_2 <- c(15:20)

result <- array(c(vec_1, vec_2), dim = c(3, 3, 2))

result

, , 1

     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    2   15   18
[2,]    3   16   19
[3,]    4   17   20

, , 2

     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    2   15   18
[2,]    3   16   19
[3,]    4   17   20

class(result)
[1] "array"
```

- qual é a lógica por de trás da criação de um `array` (como fiz no exemplo acima)?
- em que situações o uso do `array` é útil em `r`?
- como extrair as matrizes presentes no `array`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Um array, no `R`, é uma forma generalizada da matriz.

Um vetor tem apenas uma dimensão: tamanho. A matriz tem apenas duas dimensões: linhas e colunas. Um array pode ser `n` dimensões.

Caso vetor

```
library(magrittr)
array(1:12) %>% 
  print() %>% 
  dim()

[1]  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11 12
[1] 12
```

Caso matriz

```
array(1:12, c(3, 4)) %>% 
  print() %>% 
  dim()

     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
[1,]    1    4    7   10
[2,]    2    5    8   11
[3,]    3    6    9   12
[1] 3 4
```

Caso geral

```
array(1:12, c(2, 3, 2)) %>% 
  print() %>% 
  dim()

, , 1

     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    1    3    5
[2,]    2    4    6

, , 2

     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    7    9   11
[2,]    8   10   12

[1] 2 3 2
```

Caso geral com 4 dimensões

```
array(1:16, c(2, 2, 2, 2)) %>% 
  print() %>% 
  dim()

, , 1, 1

     [,1] [,2]
[1,]    1    3
[2,]    2    4

, , 2, 1

     [,1] [,2]
[1,]    5    7
[2,]    6    8

, , 1, 2

     [,1] [,2]
[1,]    9   11
[2,]   10   12

, , 2, 2

     [,1] [,2]
[1,]   13   15
[2,]   14   16

[1] 2 2 2 2
```

Então, sim, ele é inútil na maior parte dos casos porque a maior parte dos casos queremos lidar com esses casos específicos de  *arrays* que são os vetores e as matrizes.

> qual é a lógica por de trás da criação de um array (como fiz no exemplo acima)?

A lógica é a mesma da matriz. No caso dado acima a matriz foi duplicada porque ele foi reciclada, você pediu para ser criado um array com 18 elementos (3 * 3 * 2), mas forneceu apenas 9, então eles foram reciclados.

> em que situações o uso do array é útil em r?

Um array pode ser útil quando você precisar de mais de 2 dimensões. Imagine que você quer criar uma forma para visualizar e resolver cubos mágicos (*Rubik's cube*). Neste caso uma matriz ou um vetor não seriam suficientes e acabaríamos lançando mão de usar um array de dimensões `c(3, 3, 6)`. Outra aplicação possível é ler imagens coloridas que são compostas de 3 canais, cada um com uma matriz de intensidade de cores. Neste caso uma imagem com 800x600 pixel teria as dimensões `c(800, 600, 3)`.

```
img <- jpeg::readJPEG(system.file("img", "Rlogo.jpg", package="jpeg"))
str(img)
# num [1:76, 1:100, 1:3] 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
is.array(img)
# [1] TRUE
```

> como extrair as matrizes presentes no array?

Tomando o último array como exemplo, é possível fazer um *subset* da mesma forma que fazemos com matrizes, mas respeitando o número de dimensões do `array`.

```
meu_array <- array(1:16, c(2, 2, 2, 2))
meu_array[2, 2, , ]
     [,1] [,2]
[1,]    4   12
[2,]    8   16
```

No exemplo acima selecionamos a segunda linha da segunda coluna de cada uma das terceiras e quarta dimensões.

Caso o número de dimensões não seja respeitado, teremos uma erro.

```
meu_array[2, 2]
Error in meu_array[2, 2] : incorrect number of dimensions
```

Comment: Outro exemplo: a primeira vez que tive que utilizar arrays foi num projeto que envolvia simulações. Tinha vários estimadores para um certo parâmetro, digamos `E` estimadores e respetivas variâncias. Isto dá uma matriz `2*E`. Agora corra `R` vezes e guarde os resultados num array `2*E*R`.